# Ruby on Rails after bootstrap install HTML on static pages not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website for a friend using ROR like and am formatting using Bootstrap. I creates a couple of static pages, for example a home page. After running bundle install and adding bootstrap css framework,and restarting the server none of the html written on any of the pages is showing up. However, the application.html.erb is rendering just fine, but it's just a simple header.

In my gem file I added:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
```

Next I created a custom.scss file and added:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

I then added this to my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Here is the code from my Application.html.erb which runs just fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <Title>Real Life Magic Make-Believe</Title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse", id: "nav">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "REAL LIFE MAGIC MAKE-BELIEVE", root_path, id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path, id: "l1" %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "About", about_path,  id: "l1"%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", contact_path,  id: "l1"%></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

And here is a example of code that wont even load:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class= "center jumbotron">
    <body>
        <h1>REAL LIFE MAGIC MAKE-BELIEVE</h1>
        <p>
          Welcome to the home page
        </p>
    </body>
</div>
```

Comment: If what you want to build is just a static website, then Rails maybe an overkill. You can try [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/), it's a static site builder.

Comment: you probably didn't add the assets to your application.css and application.js

Comment: I did add both the js and application assets, like I said application.html.erb is rendering just fine in a bootstrap style

Comment: are you including the custom.scss in application.css/scss?

Answer (score 0):

ben,

It's hard to tell without seeing your settings.  Here are the instructions i followed and i got bootstrap working properly with rails.  Let me know if you followed the instructions already if not perhaps you can post your settings so we can see what goes wrong.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/bootstrap-sass/3.3.7

Comment: I tried those exact instructions, how would I share my settings with you? I am using the Cloud9 IDE

Comment: You can edit your original post and add the files by copy/paste and give them spacing according to SO instructions, see if you can copy/past the file's codes from the instructions so we can see whats going on.  I would also say, don't forget to restart your rails server if you haven't done so.

Comment: Edited my main post. I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: ben, can you rename your custom.scss back to application.scss - restart your rails server and try again?  Also, the html you are working on, does it load at all? do you see any errors when it loads?